# Why is there a question mark before a folder in PhpStorm Local Changes panel?

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, phpstorm

I'm trying to commit a WordPress theme folder to my GIT repo, but I can't either add it to VCS or commit the folder, there's a tiny question mark symbol before the specific folder.

Any suggestions?

[image: New WordPress theme folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem it was in my .gitignore file, excluding somehow the whole themes folder.